# how to get the facebooklogin with custom login button

Tags: android

I am trying to get the facebook login for authentication in my app it is done but the problem is when i tried to logout inside the logout its not working can anyone help me please. the code is give below

```
public class Facebooklogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    ImageView ivFacebook,btnLogout;
    Facebook fb;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    String APP_ID;
    private SharedPreferences sp;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

        sp=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token=sp.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires=sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if(access_token !=null)
        {
            fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires !=0)
        {
            fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        APP_ID=getString(R.string.facebook_app_id);
        fb=new Facebook(APP_ID);

        ivFacebook=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivFacebook);
        ivFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void updateButton()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(Facebooklogin.this,MainAct.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(fb.session != null && fb.session.isOpened())
        {
            try {
//                fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                updateButton();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else {
            fb.authorize(Facebooklogin.this, new String[] {"email"},new DialogListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Editor editor=sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    updateButton();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any lines for logout here, you can clear the session in order to perform the logout.

```
        if (session != null){
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        session = null;
    }
```

Also remove the tokens from the shared preferences and , note that you are using tan older version of facebook api here. Above methods are deprecated now.

Comment: may be you can accept this as the answer, if it helped you